# Auto Task - Optimizer statistics gathering - Log

Tags: oracle, optimization, statistics

I have setup the Optimizer Statistics Gathering via "Automated Maintenance Tasks" in Cloud Control.
Is there a log for the Auto Task job to see which objects it gathered stats on?

I can list the tables on which the stats were gathered by checking dba_tables by date.

Answer (score 0):

The data dictionary views `DBA_OPTSTAT_OPERATIONS` and `DBA_OPTSTAT_OPERATION_TASKS` provide summaries and details of optimizer statistics gathering operations.

```
--Optimizer statistics gathering.
select *
from dba_optstat_operations
order by start_time desc;

--Optimizer statistics gathering details.
select *
from dba_optstat_operation_tasks
order by start_time desc;
```

Comment: Do you know what determines how long the operation history is retained? Looking at the history for 'gather_database_stats (auto)', it only goes back 10 days. We have stats history retention set to 10. Coincidence? I'd really like to see a month or two.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I don't think it's a coincidence. I checked a few databases and the oldest rows from the operations history always matches the retention value from the query `SELECT DBMS_STATS.GET_STATS_HISTORY_RETENTION FROM DUAL;`